# Gmail Archive versus Thunderbird Archive?

Tags: gmail, thunderbird, archiving

Can anyone explain the difference here?  I have my Gmail accounts setup to use Imap but it appears my archive in gmail is not the same as my archive in Thunderbird?

Perhaps I am missing something here but the end result I want is that when I archive a message in Gmail or Thunderbird, they both end up in my Gmail Archives and not in my inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know, gmail "archives" by tagging messages and thunderbird moves them, so picking one or the other for both systems should work.

Comment: How do I get thunderbird to see my gmail tags?

Comment: @Chris: Gmail's IMAP server presents tags as IMAP folders. A message is "archived" when it is removed from `INBOX`.